# How to use \@ifnextchar to create a "table of references" macro?

Tags: recursion

At the bottom of every section in a big policy manual I need to include a table of references to a procedures manual like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Procedures} \\
  \hline
  %fyi PM = Procedures Manual
  PM \ref{PM-tyinglaces} & \nameref{PM-tyinglaces} \\ 
  PM \ref{PM-polishshoes & \nameref{PM-polishshoes} \\
  PM \ref{PM-ironshirt} & \nameref{PM-ironshirt} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Of course since every table is formatted the same I'd really like a macro with syntax similar to:

```
%\procedurelist{firstlabel}{nextlabel}...{nthlabel}
%
\procedurelist{PM-tyinglaces}{PM-polishshoes}{PM-ironshirt}
```

A single comma deliminated parameter would be okay too.  My attempt is found below.  I just can't get it to close the table, somehow it breaks when I include the closing \hline.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\procedurelist}[1]{%
    \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Procedures} \\
    \hline
    PM \ref{#1} & \nameref{#1} \\%
    \checknextarg
}
\newcommand{\checknextarg}{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{%
        \consumenextarg
    }{%
        \hline  %causes error?
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    }
}
\newcommand{\consumenextarg}[1]{%
    PM \ref{#1} & \nameref{#1} \\%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{%
        \consumenextarg
    }{%
        \hline %causes error?
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    }
}
\makeatother
```

How do I achieve my goal?

What am I doing wrong in my macro?

Comment: The error of the `\hline` is caused because you used `\checknextarg` which isn't expandable as it uses `\@ifnextchar` which is not expandable. Then you want to issue a `\noalign` which is not the first token in that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend using a syntax such as

```
\procedurelist{a}{b}{c}...{z}
```

and much prefer something like

```
\procedurelist{a,b,c,...,z}
```

It is not really difficult to do the way you imagined. The trick is to build the table body in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\procedurelist}{%
  \proclist@body={}%
  \proclist@start
}

\newtoks\proclist@body
\newcommand{\proclist@start}{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup\proclist@absorb\proclist@finish
}
\newcommand{\proclist@absorb}[1]{%
  \proclist@body=\expandafter{%
    \the\proclist@body
    PM~\ref{#1} & \nameref{#1} \\%
  }%
  \proclist@start
}
\newcommand{\proclist@finish}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \the\proclist@body
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Tie laces}\label{PM-tyinglaces}
\section{Polish shoes}\label{PM-polishshoes}
\section{Iron shirt}\label{PM-ironshirt}

\section{End}

\procedurelist{PM-tyinglaces}{PM-polishshoes}{PM-ironshirt}

\end{document}
```

The other approach with a comma separated list is easier with `expl3`, which already has features for processing comma separated lists and cycling over them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\procedurelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq
     {
      PM~\ref{##1} & \nameref{##1}
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq { \\ } \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Tie laces}\label{PM-tyinglaces}
\section{Polish shoes}\label{PM-polishshoes}
\section{Iron shirt}\label{PM-ironshirt}

\section{End}

\procedurelist{PM-tyinglaces,PM-polishshoes,PM-ironshirt}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\procedurelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq
     {
      \ref{##1} & \nameref{##1}
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{cl}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PM}} & \textbf{Name} \\
  \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq { \\ } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__kjc_procedurelist_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Tie laces}\label{PM-tyinglaces}
\section{Polish shoes}\label{PM-polishshoes}
\section{Iron shirt}\label{PM-ironshirt}

\section{End}

\procedurelist{PM-tyinglaces,PM-polishshoes,PM-ironshirt}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler implementation, once one gets the hang of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\procedurelist}{m}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__kjc_procedurelist_row:n { \ref{##1} & \nameref{##1} \\ }
  \begin{tabular}{cl}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PM}} & \textbf{Name} \\
  \midrule
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__kjc_procedurelist_row:n
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Tie laces}\label{PM-tyinglaces}
\section{Polish shoes}\label{PM-polishshoes}
\section{Iron shirt}\label{PM-ironshirt}

\section{End}

\procedurelist{PM-tyinglaces,PM-polishshoes,PM-ironshirt}  

\end{document}
```

With this approach the `\__kjc_procedurelist_row:n` function could be defined outside the main command. However one can also improve this by allowing to change the default on the fly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\procedurelist}{om}
 {
  \IfValueT{#1}
   {
    \cs_set:Nn \__kjc_procedurelist_row:n { #1 }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{cl}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PM}} & \textbf{Name} \\
  \midrule
  \clist_map_function:nN { #2 } \__kjc_procedurelist_row:n
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__kjc_procedurelist_row:n { \ref{#1} & \nameref{#1} \\ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Tie laces}\label{PM-tyinglaces}
\section{Polish shoes}\label{PM-polishshoes}
\section{Iron shirt}\label{PM-ironshirt}

\section{End}

\procedurelist{
  PM-tyinglaces,
  PM-polishshoes,
  PM-ironshirt
}
\procedurelist[\ref{#1} & \textit{\nameref{#1}} \\]{
  PM-tyinglaces,
  PM-polishshoes,
  PM-ironshirt
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you define `\__kjc_procedurelist_tmp:n` every time `\procedurelist` is called in your last implementation? Should be better performing if set only once (assuming `\procedurelist` is called more than once).

Comment: @Skillmon Sure. Let me add something.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to first grab all those arguments and store them somewhere (here in `\procedurelist@content`). After you grabbed all arguments you can then output the formatted table. This way you don't have any unexpandable tests inside of the table blocking any `\noalign`s.

Example code (I removed the `\nameref`s and the surrounding `table` as that doesn't make sense if the only allowed placement is `H` and you don't use a caption):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\procedurelist@content{}
\newcommand*\procedurelist@checknext
  {%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup
      {\procedurelist@eatnext}
      {\procedurelist@shipout}%
  }
\newcommand\procedurelist[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\procedurelist@content{PM \ref{#1} & #1 \\}%
    \procedurelist@checknext
  }
\newcommand\procedurelist@eatnext[1]
  {%
    \edef\procedurelist@content
      {\unexpanded\expandafter{\procedurelist@content PM \ref{#1} & #1 \\}}%
    \procedurelist@checknext
  }
\newcommand*\procedurelist@shipout
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Procedures} \\
      \hline
      \procedurelist@content
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\procedurelist{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `\xintFor` (which is not expandable loop, but nevertheless works in tabulars...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand{\procedurelist}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cl}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PM}} & \textbf{Name} \\
  \midrule
  \xintFor ##1 in {#1}\do {\ref{##1} & \nameref{##1} \\ }
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Tie laces}\label{PM-tyinglaces}
\section{Polish shoes}\label{PM-polishshoes}
\section{Iron shirt}\label{PM-ironshirt}

\section{End}

\procedurelist{PM-tyinglaces,PM-polishshoes,PM-ironshirt}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With mark-up such as `\procedurelist{{PM-tyinglaces}{PM-polishshoes}{PM-ironshirt}}`, same code as in my answer with `\xintFor ##1 in {#1}` replaced by `\xintFor* #1 in {##1}`. (slightly more efficient as any way `\xintFor` converts the comma separated values into the braced values expected by `\xintFor*`; but with only 3 values...)